# Is Mikkel Toivosson's health bar supposed to refill?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I keep trying to beat this fight at the end of The Championship Fight quest and I can only get him down to about half health before he quickly runs back to where he is at the beginning of the fight and his health recharges very rapidly until the bar is full. He does this repeatedly while I am fighting him. Am I doing something wrong or is my game broken?

Comment: Are you trying to kite him? Mobs have a leash distance, which means that when they go past that limit they will reset.

Comment: Ah yeah, that was it. It's crazy that as a ranged character on a wide open frozen lake I can't just keep dodging backwards. Once I started dodging around just in the starting area I was able to beat him.

Comment: Occasionally a mob will bug and display this behavior, even though it is still well within its area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mobs can only go so far from where you initially engage them otherwise they will hit their 'leash' and reset. Try kiting mobs in circles rather than just dodging backwards all the time.

The reasoning behind this behaviour is to stop what happened in certain early MMORPG's where people would end up with 'train's of creatures trailing behind them until eventually they died, usually taking several other people along with them.

Comment: I understand the point of having it for random mobs in a wide-open world but having it in a personal story instance where I was already restricted in my movement and there was no way we could ever interact with any other players was strange.

Comment: @p5ycho_p3nguin: Yea, I do get that. Likely it's probably because it was easier to implement as an all or nothing kind of thing. Also because you do want it in some instances, ie. dungeons. We'll never know the exact reasons behind why they leash in your personal story, just that they do and we should avoid it. Personally, I've not had too many issues with it on my necro.